# Codename one LocationManager.getLocationManager() null

Tags: codenameone

When can LocationManager.getLocationManager() return null ?

GPS is switched off ?
Location not available from carrier ?

I think it throws an IOException in these cases ?

Can it return a null ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can return null for some older J2ME devices which might not have support for location (it will work for most recent J2ME devices too). It shouldn't return null for other cases e.g. iOS, Android, Windows Phone etc..